# Incrementing number +1 dependending from how many <span id="countdown"> are in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello all that's my code:

```
<span id="countdown">2014-25-09</span>
<span id="countdown">2015-25-09</span>
<span id="countdown">2016-25-09</span>
```

Now the problem is that works only the first span id ="countdown" because the right syntax would be:

```
<span id="countdown1">2014-25-09</span>
<span id="countdown2">2015-25-09</span>
<span id="countdown3">2016-25-09</span>.
```

Now: I've found some code to count :

```
var count = $('span#countdown').length;
```

But i can't apply the number to the span id. Help?!

Comment: the template that generates multiple elements with the same id is WRONG

Comment: id should be unique

Comment: If you want to count then use the attribute selector `var count = $('span[id=countdown]').length;`

Comment: why you dont use classes instead ids ? class="countdown" and $('span.countdown').length; ?

Comment: The question to ask is "why do you need to have an id on each element ? Is it really necessary ?" I bet it's not, and classes should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript ID is used to unique identification of an element in page and all methods related to ID are created in such a way.
So If you use to get element using ID it find the only first occurrence of element having searching ID in page.

If you want to filter elements than you need to use class attribute of element.

Like -

```
<span class="countdown" id="countdown1">2014-25-09</span>
<span class="countdown" id="countdown2">2015-25-09</span>
<span class="countdown" id="countdown3">2016-25-09</span>
```

Now you can use jquery to count all span having class "countdown"

```
var count = $('span.countdown').length;
```

And increment by one as per your requirment

```
count += 1;
```

You can go through each span element using jQuery each method or change each element attribute like in below code I am changin id from "countdown" to "new"
here $(this) is pointing to current element in loop.

```
$('.testimonial').each(function(i, obj) {
    var newID = "new" + i  // adding number following "new" string like new1, new2 .... 
    $(this).attr('id',newID);
});
```

Comment: Anupam the problem is that id="countdownX" depends from the number of "counter" in the same page

Comment: Pigi you can use $('span.countdown')length method to count no of existing elements in current page and that increment by one and add attribute Id to new added element if you are creating them dynamically

Answer (score 2):

The spans should not all have the same ID.  You could add a class to them of `countdown`, then you can do

```
var count = $('span.countdown').length;
```

if you MUST use ID's, you can use the starts with selector:

```
var count = $('span[id^="countdown"]').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use class. Your html would look like:

```
<span class="countdown" id="countdown1">2014-25-09</span>
<span class="countdown" id="countdown2">2015-25-09</span>
<span class="countdown" id="countdown3">2016-25-09</span>
```

And for JS, you really don't need jQuery. Just do,

```
var countdown = document.getElementsByClassName("countdown");
```

It will return an array of all the elements with class `countdown`.

To see its length, you can do,

```
countdown.length;
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

since you MUST give `id` uniquely, you have to use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/doniyor/L83guddg/

```
var count = $('span.countdown').length;
```